# Python - Parse XML with repeated tags using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have the following XML content:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Sub Version</key><integer>2</integer>
    <dict>
        <key>1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ID</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Frank</string>
        </dict>
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ID</key><integer>2</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Richard</string>
        </dict>
        <key>3</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ID</key><integer>3</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Sophia</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>Persons</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>Persons</string>
            <key>Description</key><string>empty</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm having a hard time retrieving the names since this XML tags names are all the same and have no attributes.
So far I've tried to access it using iteration over the "second depth dict" but I can't retrieve just what I want.

What I got:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for i in root.find('dict').find('dict').iter('dict'):
    print ([j.text for j in i])
```

The output I want:

```
Frank
Richard
Sophia
```

Does anyone know how to access these values with such tags?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Python code you have so far, as well as the expected output. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If on the Mac, please look at [plistlib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/plistlib.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using lxml instead:

```
from lxml import etree
plist = """your xml above"""

doc = etree.fromstring(plist)
doc.xpath('//dict/dict/key["name"]/following-sibling::string/text()')
```

output:

```
['Frank', 'Richard', 'Sophia']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! For information I noticed that it also work (better?) with key[text()="Name"] instead of key["name"], the latter one does not seem to really take into account the "name" value after making some tests

Comment: @Reedy Yup, the magic of xpath: `key[text()="Name"]`, `key["name"]`and `key[.="name"]` are equivalent and all work...